# Помогает ли чтение грамотности?

Tags: грамотная-речь, общие-вопросы

На вопрос "как повысить грамотность" существует стандартный ответ: "Много читать". Честно говоря, у меня этот постулат вызывает некоторые сомнения. Чтобы чтение повлияло на грамотность, нужно, читая, видеть перед глазами буквы и анализировать написанные слова, но, не знаю, как другие, но я, если книга интересная, вижу не буквы, а сюжет, героев, события, если можно так сказать "смотрю внутреннее кино".
С другой стороны, возможно, что-то откладывается на подсознании - не знаю. Но скажу по себе: я всегда читала очень много, но грамотно писать стала только после курсов по методике для тех, у кого образное мышление (там все правила подаются в образах и картинках).
А что на этот счет думают специалисты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под грамотностью. Чтение книг способствует расширению словарного запаса и формированию грамотной речи. У книголюба редко возникают моменты когда он не в состоянии выразить свою мысль так, чтобы она была понятна окружающим. Ну и совсем грубые орфографические ошибки уровня начальной школы читающий много человек вряд ли совершит.

Что же касается прочих особенностей орфографии, то к сожалению, если у человека не фотографическая память чтение мало помогает в освоении правил, хотя и помогает запоминать исключения. Человек читает не по слогам, а всё слово целиком, при этом, если сознание не заострено на орфограммах, то для читающего нет особой разницы между "иску**сс**твом" и "иску**с**твом". Про пунктуацию, думаю говорить излишне, при быстром чтении её как правило игнорируют. Да и если б было не так, механическое запоминание знаков препинания ничего бы не дало, так как в пунктуации важны не сами знаки, а конструкции предложений, которые без анализа, попросту незаметны.

Answer (score 2):

Грамотность (в письменной речи) - это: 1)умение писать безошибочно; 2)умение находить ошибки в написанном другим человеком.  1) для этого надо: а) знать все правила русского языка и все исключения из них, что возможно у очень редких людей; б) читать много литературно выверенных текстов, интуитивно запоминая строение фраз, написание слов и пунктуацию; однако порою такой "грамотей" не в состоянии объяснить, почему это написано так, а не иначе - такое могут проявить не очень многие (я из их числа). Помогает ли чтение такой грамотности? Грамотности по п. 1) а) почти нет; грамотности по п. 2) а) - ответ положителен; 2) а) возможно, но не обязательно; 2) б) пожалуй, возможно

Answer (score 2):

Интуитивная грамотность, формируемая чтением (только хорошо сделанных книг, желательно изданных в Советском Союзе), имеет свои пределы. Школьное образование тоже имеет свои пределы. Достаточно ли их? Кому как. Чтобы человек стал по-настоящему грамотным, то есть свободным в письменном выражении мысли, его нужно научить главному - самообразованию: какими словарями пользоваться, в какие справочники заглядывать. Их не так уж много: толковый, орфографический, синонимов да Розенталь с Грамота.ру - базовый набор. И всё легко найти в Интернете. Можно штудировать систематично, а можно заглядывать по мере надобности.

Только зачем, если грамотность - роскошь, то есть вещь труднодоступная и бесполезная? А самооценку можно повысить с помощью мифа - о врожденной грамотности, зверином чутье на ошибки (встречала и такое в резюме), родовой травме, приведшей к совершенному знанию языка, или о благотворном влиянии жизни в России на языковые способности (многие уверены, что знают русский в совершенстве просто потому, что думают по-русски).

Comment: >> Только зачем, если грамотность - роскошь, то есть вещь труднодоступная и бесполезная?

Почему роскошь-то? Почему труднодоступная вещь? Вот это тоже миф, наряду с врожденной грамотностью. Кто мешает?

Comment: Никто не мешает - некогда. Надо деньги зарабатывать, детей растить, ремонты делать... Какая грамотность? Даже корректорам некогда справочник открыть, потому что всё срочно и быстро.

Answer (score 1):

Надо много читать *в детстве*, причем чем раньше, тем лучше. Потом уже не будет такого эффекта.
Впрочем, это можно отнести не только к грамотности. Маленький ребенок впитывает *всё* значительно быстрее и качественнее.

Comment: Я читать научился раньше чем говорить, причём это никакое не преувеличение (читаю с 3-х лет, разборчиво говорю с 4-х). К 10 годам осилил почти всю домашнюю библиотеку (это не менее двух тысяч экземпляров) и активно посещал библиотеки городские. Оценка за грамотность в школе никогда не поднималась выше четвёрки, начиная с 7-го класса только "3" или "2".

Comment: Да? А когда сюда пишете, Вордом, что ли, текст проверяете? Но Ворд в пунктуации слабоват, да и в орфографии может налепить чудес...

Comment: Орфографию я, благодаря встроенным редакторам подтянул ещё на заре своего освоения интернета, пунктуацию уже на этом форуме чуть выправил. Хотя всё равно ошибки периодически случаются, особенно если пишу с мобильника. В прошлом году написал диктант для 7-го класса, одна орфографическая, семь пунктуационных.

Answer (score 0):

ТОЧКА ЗРЕНИЯ (как интуиция грамматику победила)

Обучение правописанию изначально опиралось на грамматику. Основателем грамматической школы считается Ломоносов, который  первым установил нормы письма,  систематизировал правила, приспособил их к возможностям учащихся.

Однако с конца  XIX века  заявила о себе антиграмматическая школа, и началось их великое противостояние. «Мы за умственное развитие нации, за сознательную деятельность ученика», – возмущались грамматики. «Только автоматизм и интуиция, – отвечали им «неинтеллектуальные» противники. –  Писать надо больше, зрительные образы запоминать».

Но в конце концов грамматика оттеснила интуитивную школу на второй план, и грамматическое направление продолжили те, кто в 1956 году написали для нас знаменитые правила.
    Казалось бы,  грамматика и только грамматика, но вот что мы читаем  в современной прессе: «Взрослый человек в своей орфографической практике почти никогда не следует правилам». «Люди на письме  руководствуются совсем другими представлениями – прежде всего, графическим образом слова, сложившимся у него в течение жизни под действием чтения и самостоятельного написания текстов».

Похоже на правду? Тогда кто же победил – интуиция или грамматика? Получается, что изучаем грамматические правила, а пишем по интуиции? Наверное, мы делаем что-то не так, но вот такое у нас письмо – грамматическое, плавно переходящее в интуитивное. Что ж, тоже неплохо, лишь бы переход состоялся.

Comment: >>... вот что мы читаем в современной прессе: «Взрослый человек в своей орфографической практике почти никогда не следует правилам»

Опытный водитель в своей практике вождения почти никогда не следует ПДД.
Опытный шахматист в своей практике игры почти никогда не вспоминает шахматные учебники.
И так далее, и тому подобное.

К чему волоку? Грамотный человек в своей практике почти никогда напрямую не вспоминает правила, но это не значит, что он им не следует. Собственно, полная аналогия с водителем автомобиля.

>> Похоже на правду?

Да нисколько.

Comment: Давайте на примере: выбираем слитное или раздельное написание частиц НЕ и НИ.  Всего-то два шага для правильного решения, и при этом три-четыре десятка правил. И вот интересно, как вы,  не зная этих правил или не вспомнив их напрямую, будете записывать, к примеру,  такой простенький текст: "Уж я к ней и так и этак, со словами и без слов,Обломал не мало веток, наломал не мало дров". Как правильно: слитно или раздельно? А вдруг здесь частица НИ, ведь слово "нимало тоже существует?

Comment: Не так давно мне пришлось наблюдать такую сценку: возмущенная родительница рассказывает подруге, как учительница обидела ее сына, который написал слово правильно, но объяснить выбор нужной буквы  не смог. Вот он - грамотный человек? Он следовал каким-нибудь правилам или писал по интуиции? А может быть, он просто угадал ответ по принципу  фифти-фифти.

Comment: Про родительницу и учитеьницу - это всего лишь один случай. Глобальных выводов делать нельзя. А что значит "обидела"? Снизила оценку? Уж эти мне мамочки... Нет, чтобы объяснить сыну: мол, надо не только грамотно писать, но и уметь объяснить!
Ближе к делу! Какие три-четыре десятка правил? "Нимало" значит "нисколько", и тут опять же помогает чтение книг. Не подходит. Отрицания нет - слитно. Всего один принцип, где ваши четыре десятка?!

Comment: Про мамочку совершенно реальный случай: из-за сниженной оценки она как раз собиралась писать жалобу директору. Но сейчас оценки - дело серьезное, от хорошего образования в жизни много  зависит. А в приведенном примере авторское решение: НЕ можно писать слитно или раздельно. И ваш диагноз "есть или нет отрицания" слишком субъективен, здесь нужны более конкретные доказательства. Вот еще примеры: "Мало не  много,  много не  мало.   Ворону  отведено ни много ни мало – триста лет жизни! Десять лет – не много и не мало".  Справитесь? И поконкретнее, пожалуйста, чтобы учительница приняла ответ.

Comment: >> А в приведенном примере авторское решение: НЕ можно писать слитно или раздельно.

А вот "авторское решение" к академической (да и школьной) грамматике относится... весьма опосредованно, скажем так. Хозяин - барин. Вот Горький любил тире - давайте устраивать диктанты из Горького и ставить всем пары. А "обломал немало веток, наломал немало дров" нормально нужно писать слитно.

Да, такие сочетания, как "ни много ни мало" надо запоминать. Оно само запоминается, если книжки читать.
Это вторая фраза. Остальные две просто смешные. Отрицание налицо.

Comment: В тексте песни одинаково часто можно встретить как слитное, так и раздельное написание. Варианты отличаются оттенками значений: при слитном написании - немало вЕток, при раздельном написании - не мАло веток, поэтому раздельный вариант более выразителен. Далее: в грамматической орфографии запоминать ничего не рекомендуется, а рекомендуется всё объяснять. "Ни мало ни много" - это устойчивое словосочетание, в котором частица НИ совмещает значения отрицания и усиления, в то время как в выражении "не много и не мало" только отрицание. Так что сами видите, можно поставить только "удовлетворительно"

Comment: Ну и что... Я ж не претендую? Тем более что это уж никак не для школьной программы, даже не для олимпиад вопросы. Потому что ответы неоднозначные. Вы напираете на чрезмерную сложность правил, но нормальные выпускники (а на дебилов ориентироваться не стоит) пишут вполне себе грамотно. Значит, сложность правил ни при чем.

Comment: "Немало"=много, "не мало"=это не мало, но вовсе не и не обязательно, что много. Учительница в таких спорных случаях должна принять ответ ученика как правильный. Ведь именно написание подскажет нам, что хотел сказать ученик. Для словарных диктантов и тестов такие примеры не подходят, учитель не должен их включать. Отрицание - раздельно, утверждение - слитно - это правило. Но есть методический прием, практически универсальный для существительных, прилагательных и наречий на -О(Е)- это замена на синоним. Можно- пиши слитно, нет - раздельно.

Comment: Все остальное на эту тему у Розенталя в справочнике - примеры, а не новые правила.

Answer (score 0):

Жаль тут опросов нет.

Однако, на своём опыте могу сказать, что "интуитивной грамотностью", как правило, обладают не те, кто много читает, а те, кто с детства слышит "правильную" речь. Коренные петербуржцы в нескольких поколениях, "потомственные интеллигенты" и т.п. Они просто пишут "как говорят". А, вот, чтоб приобрести "интуитивную грамотность" читая - необходимо "проговаривать" читаемый текст хотя-бы "про себя".