# Что такое интуитивная грамотность?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Есть такое понятие как "интуитивная грамотность" или "чувство языка". То есть, человек интуитивно пишет грамотно, не помня из школьной программы ни одного правила. Я слышала о таком явлении и обо мне учительница в школе говорила, что у меня эта интуитивная грамотность есть (хотя я что-то ее за собой не замечаю, все-таки стараюсь пользоваться правилами))). И я, честно говоря, не могу понять, что это вообще такое? Если не вдаваться в область эзотерики, то интуиция - это действие безусловных рефлексов и инстинктов, как мне кажется. Но какой рефлекс и инстинкт может отвечать за грамотность? Тогда объяснение - только нечто из области непознанного. Или же понятие "интуитивная грамотность" вообще вымышленное? Что вы об этом думаете?
*Вроде бы, такого вопроса тут не задавали - я специально поискала, прежде чем писать.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С материалистической точки зрения, интуиция - это внесознательное мышление. Человек проделывает всю мыслительную операцию, но из-за того, что она проходит без участия сознания, воспринимает лишь конечный ответ, а цепочку рассуждений, приведшую к нему, воспроизвести не в состоянии. Из-за особенностей мышления, подобное чаще всего происходит у представительниц прекрасного пола, что и порождает так называемую женскую логику.

Применительно к грамотности, "интуитивная грамотность" - это бессознательное воспроизведение правил орфографии и пунктуации, на основе ранее прочитанных текстов или усвоенных правил.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос затрагивали [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36662/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1). Просто он был иначе сформулирован.
Если вкратце - большинство сходится в том, что "интуитивная грамотность" существует, но расходится в том, что это такое.
Лично я полагаю, что "интуитивная грамотность" чаще всего свойственна тем, кто "правильно" говорит (например - коренным петербуржцам в нескольких поколениях). Они просто пишут как произносят.
Наиболее распространённое мнение - "интуитивная грамотность" вырабатывается при чтении. К сожалению, ею обладают далеко не все любители читать.
Есть версия, что "интуитивная грамотность" - результат тренировки. Правда, одни говорят, что надо просто много писать, другие - что надо писать под диктовку.

Comment: Вот-вот! Я всегда читала очень много, а грамотно писать начала только в последних классах школы.

Answer (score 2):

Интуитивная грамотность - это рефлекторное воспроизведение в памяти прежнего опыта работы с литературными текстами, с письмом на бумаге и частично со слуховым общением с людьми и аудиозаписями. У каждого свои возможности такой грамотности, ограниченные в той или иной степени. И если у кого-то ярко выражены такие способности, говорят о врождённой грамотности, хотя на самом деле таковой с материалистической точки зрения существовать не может в принципе... Это очень похоже на ответ [@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7).

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, но почему-то люди с т.н. интуитивной грамотностью чаще всего (других я не встречал) заканчивали советскую школу. Молодежь (в том числе и я) в основном пишет, основываясь на правила. Я всегда задаю себе вопрос: смог бы ли я писать грамотно, если бы не окончил факультет лингвистики?

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, обладают ли, к примеру, англичане интуитивной грамотностью? Думается, что это, скорее, наше национальное  понятие.

Дело в том, что между записью русской речи и ее устным вариантом  существует разница, закономерность которой можно проследить, в том числе на подсознательном уровне. Знаки пунктуации также связаны со структурой предложения: много раз виденные конструкции запоминаются интуитивно. Люди с интуитивной грамотностью легче фиксируют такую связь и отражают ее на письме. Интуиция - врожденное качество, все люди обладают интуицией, но в разной степени.

Наши правила, основанные на грамматике, к грамматике практически не обращаются, обучение же идет по следующему принципу: обратите ВНИМАНИЕ на то, что, к примеру, в слове "дорога" мы произносим гласную А, а пишем гласную О. Много раз "обращенное внимание" позволяет в конце концов запомнить нужную  информацию, она как бы усваивается подсознательно.  В результате человек получает навык грамотного письма, а правила впоследствии обычно забывает. В то же время для разных людей этот процесс осуществляется  в разные сроки и с различным успехом.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, я буду в меньшинстве, но я против понятия интуитивной грамотности, поскольку оно понимается как синоним грамотности. На самом же деле существует грамотность, безграмотность и промежуточный вариант - приемлемый уровень, формируемый школьной программой. А волшебная грамотность без усилий, передаваемая по наследству, возникающая вследствие родовой травмы, развитой интуиции или общей "няшности" ее носителя, - миф. На каждое "интуитивно грамотное" предложение приходится "интуитивно безграмотное". Просто людям приятно думать, что они умные, красивые, хорошие и грамотные - просто так, по факту своего рождения.

Answer (score 1):

Чушь! Я насчёт того, что люди с интуитивной грамотностью оканчивали советскую школу. Я родился в 21 веке (2001 г), но, тем не менее, обладаю интуитивной грамотностью. Мама это объясняет тем, что я начал рано читать (4 - 4,5 лет). И, что самое интересное, обладаю дефектом речи - картавлю :) Ещё мой первый логопед говорил ,что обычно, если у человека проблемы с речью, то языки даются сложно. Но я, видимо, исключение :)

Answer (score 0):

Большое число прочитанных книг, общение с культурными и грамотными людьми, чтение газет, построение собственных мыслей с попытками грамотного описания каждого слова, все это приводит к отпечатыванию отдельных правил а порой и слов в памяти подсознательно. И человек правильно пишет и произносит не потому что он выучил правило, а потому что иначе не может.